# Typescript return type based on argument with types not function overloading

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

So im trying to make a single function GetSet, with 2 args, one is the index, and the other one is a value, if the value is not given, the func should return a value (get), if it is given it should return nothing (set). I know i can do something like this using function overloading which works.

```js
function GetSet<T>(i: number):T
function GetSet<T>(i: number, val: T):void
function GetSet<T>(i: number, val?: T): T | void {
    if (val === undefined)
        return 1 as unknown as T // just an example
    else 
        return
}

const returnsNumber = GetSet<string>(1)
const returnsVoid   = GetSet<string>(1, 'test')
```

But i need it in a generic type way so i tried this,

```js
type GetSetType<T> = {
    <T>(i: number) : T
    <T>(i: number, val: T) : void
    <T>(i: number, val?: T | undefined) : T | void
}

const test: GetSetType<number> = (i: number, val?: number) => {
    if (val === undefined)
        return 1
    else 
        return
}
```

But it doesnt work, what am i doing wrong?

```js
const returnsUnknown = test(1)
```

Comment: Just to understand your situation better: why isn't the first example with function overloading acceptable to you? If you want to avoid having to specify the type argument every time you call it, you could 'alias' it by doing e.g. `const test = GetSet<string>;` and calling `test(...)` instead of `GetSet<string>(...)`

Comment: i want to specify specific function for each type

Comment: My suggestion here looks like [this](https://tsplay.dev/m3yZ1w).  You probably don't want `GetSetType<number>` to be generic in `U extends number`, because otherwise someone could call it like `test<3>(1)` and it claims to return exactly `3` even though the implementation doesn't work that way.   You don't need the third call signature... your original `GetSet` function only has two call signatures; the implementation signature (with `T | void`) is not seen by callers. Does this meet your needs? If so I can write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Figured out why, the `T` in `GetSetType<T>` and `T` in each function are recognized as completely different things. So i gotta use something like this.

```js
type GetSetType<T> = {
    <U extends T>(i: number) : U
    <U extends T>(i: number, val: T) : void
    <U extends T>(i: number, val?: T | undefined) : U | void
}

const test: GetSetType<number> = (i: number, val?: number) => {
    if (val === undefined)
        return 1
    else 
        return
}

const returnsNumber = test(1)
```